# Why isn't $\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\tan(2x)\ dx$ equal to zero?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I know about the improper integral issue, but analyzing the graph we see that $\tan (x)$ is odd around $\pi/4$, so if we say that the positive area is $+\infty$, we know that the other one is $-\infty$.

I know that infinities can't be summed, however we know that, because of odd condition, they are the "same infinity."  So why isn't it zero?

Comment: It is simply because improper integral is not designed to capture the notion of "same infinity". Applying the definition to our case, $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \tan(2x) \, dx = \lim_{\substack{a \to (\pi/4)^- \\ b \to (\pi/4)^+}} \left(\int_{0}^{a} \tan(2x)\,dx + \int_{b}^{\pi/2} \tan(2x)\, dx \right), $$ which tests every possible different paces at which $a, b$ approach the singularity, thereby deliberately breaking the notion of "same infinity". The idea you are interested in must make use of the symmetry of the singularity, which is adopted by Cauchy's principal value.

Answer (score 11):

$$\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\tan(2x)\ dx = \int\limits_0^{\pi/4}\tan(2x)\ dx + \int\limits_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\tan(2x)\ dx $$
For the integral to exist, we need existence of both those integrals. Because those integrals do not exit, therefore neither does their sum.

There is, however, something called Cauchy's principal value, where we approach the limit at the same pace:

$$\text{p. v.}\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\tan(2x)\ dx = \lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\left( \int\limits_0^{\pi/4-\varepsilon}\tan(2x)\ dx + \int\limits_{\pi/4+\varepsilon}^{\pi/2}\tan(2x)\ dx \right)= 0 $$

Indeed the value is 0 in this case.

Comment: @David G. Stork, thank you for editing my post, I'll remember to add those next time I write something in LaTeX

Comment: @David G. Stork Those edits were in fact quite unnecessary. You’re not entitled to make pedantic or frivolous edits to someone else’s content.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor:  The poster himself disagrees, and doesn't think my edits are "frivolous."  Quite the contrary, he writes:  "@David G. Stork, thank you for editing my post, I'll remember to add those next time I write something in LaTeX."  Placing the integration limits above and below the integral sign aids legibility, as does separating the $dx$ from integrand, especially in cases such as $\int abc dx$.  (A few posters don't even include the integration variable!)